# input value not exceeding on typing

Tags: reactjs

I had to add a validation on input field, so I used this:

```
<input
  type="text"
  name={this.state.editBookData.title}
  value={this.state.toEditBookData.title}
  onChange={e => {
    let { editBookData } = this.state;
    editBookData.title = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ [editBookData.title]: e.target.value });
  }}
/>
```

Here, the line `this.setState({[editBookData.title]: e.target.value});` is stopping any typing on input.

`editBookData` is set in the state like this:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    toEditBookData: {
      id: 0,
      title: "",
      rating: ""
    }
  };
}
```

Also when I check in the console, when I type anything in the input, the name property takes only 1 character and ceases to add any other character.
please let me know why I cannot type any letters. Thanks

Comment: This is happening because you are setting editBookData.title but your value field reads from toEditBookData.

Comment: Did any of the answers work for you? Consider [accepting one of them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#answer-5235) if that’s the case.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to add a new property to the state with the same name as `editBookData.title`, but instead update the `toEditBookData` object with a new title, since that is what is used as `value` for the input.

```
<input
  type="text"
  name={this.state.editBookData.title}
  value={this.state.toEditBookData.title}
  onChange={e => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return {
        toEditBookData: { ...prevState.toEditBookData, title: value }
      };
    });
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you need two objects here. This should do the trick.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    id: 0,
    title: "",
    rating: "",
    errors: {}
  };

  handleChange = e => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    const { errors } = this.state;

    errors[name] = !!!value;
    this.setState({ [name]: value, errors });
  };

  render() {
    const { title, errors } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <label htmlFor="title">Title: </label>
        <br />
        <input
          type="text"
          name="title"
          value={title}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        <br />
        {errors.title && (
          <span style={{ color: "red" }}>Title is a required field</span>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```